# linked list implementation using array only

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers, linked-list

I have to implement one linked list type of data structure using just arrays (no malloc-only static memory).
What exactly i have to do is like this:
(1) I have an array of set of elements, lets say  array [216]={1 2 3 4}  (I will take very big size, that's why 216 here).

(2)I have to make addition at index 0,1 and 2,3 and 4,5 etc. (At index 0,1 we have"1","2", their addition is =3). this 3 is then will be positioned at last of the array (I mean after "6", so the array now is:={1 2 3 4  3}).
*This i have already implemented.*

*What i have to do is :

(3) I have to make the program like this that each element must have it's value(Suppose i call value as "Freq" in my code) and index of next element it points to and last element which has nothing to point must contain "-1" at next. Just like as below:
**I haven't done addition yet, It's intially,After addition is done it' size will grow (see at last for that please).
Before doing the addition the data structure is like this:

```
index:0 Freq: 1 Next :1
index:1 Freq: 2 Next :2  
index:2 Freq: 3 Next :3 
index:3 Freq: 4 Next :-1
```

(4)**And this porocess of pointing must be in increasing order**, I mean you can see below that i mean if we add Freq at index 0,1 we will obtain 3 then this 3 is set to be at last index on array and we can see that at index 2 the next is pointing to index 4 (not 3- as doing just above-It's done just to maintain increasing order, We just have to deal with the movement of index(every element is static(don't change it's position, just the index will point the Freq in increasing order.)).

(This part is easy to implement, I have done it.)
I have problem when i have to add at the indexes i mentioned in point (2).
The data structure must look like this:(after addition)
After doing addition:

```
index:0 Freq: 1 Next :1
index:1 Freq: 2 Next :2  
index:2 Freq: 3 Next :4 //It don't point to index 3.In order to mantain increasing order
index:3 Freq: 4 Next :5
index:4 Freq: 3 Next :3 //this is obtained by addition of Freq at index 0 and 1
index:5 Freq: 7 Next :-1 //this is obtained by addition of Freq at index 2 and 3
```

**Any idea how to implement the second part?** (after addition).
My code  is(up to addition party-Not index part):

```
struct node
{
int freq;
int next;
};
main()
{
int i,count=0,j,f,s,data_size;
struct node data[1000];


//I am skipping sime understood part

data[data_size].freq=data[f].freq+data[s].freq;//where data_size=**elementsSize+1** .In out case there are 4 elements so data_size=5.The added element is to be placed at last.That's why i too it **"elementSize+1"**.
data_size++;
}.
```

**Any ideas how to tmplement "next" part ?**

Comment: @bobah You can't use that in C.

Comment: i'm a bit lost. Are you having trouble fixing the next pointers?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski, thanks for teh reply. Yes i want to know the algorithm that how to make the next pointer of each element to point to the element which is greater then or equal to the Freq of it's own. For eg, 1 2 6 7 is an array.Initially 1's next point to 2and 2's nxt point to 6 then we do addition at index 0 and 1(we have element 1 and 2 ther) and then added element go at last of array.It became{1 2 6 7 3}, now now 2's next should point to 3 and 3's next should point to 6(to maintain increasing order just by "poitning the next-NOT BY SHIFTING OF ELEMENTS").

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski I am not able to design the algorithm for this "Next" pointing to element greater then it's Freq. I need help in that. could you please help me ?

Comment: "linked list implementation using array only" - I believe that's called a "Cursor", where the array provides the storage and you just manage indices into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about how to insert an element and keep the list in increasing order?

```
int insert(struct node *data, int new_freq, int data_size) {
    // Impossible if new_freq is less than first element,
    // because you don't have a head pointer(index)
    assert(data[0].freq <= new_freq);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; data[i].next != -1; i = data[i].next)
        if (data[data[i].next].freq > new_freq) // insert after i
            break;
    // insert at end of array if loop doesn't break

    data[data_size].freq = new_freq;
    data[data_size].next = data[i].next;
    data[i].next = data_size;
    return data_size + 1; // return new size
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is thsis assert any inbuilt function ?

Comment: It's in `assert.h`. You can just remove it if you are sure that the new freq is greater.

Comment: In the piece of code you hav written  you are assuming that the intial arrays elements(by initial elements i mean the one on which we gonna apply addition porcess) taken aready have some defined next like index:0 Freq: 1 Next :1
index:1 Freq: 2 Next :2  
index:2 Freq: 3 Next :3 
index:3 Freq: 4 Next :-1  . Am i right ?

Comment: Could you please explain me this "data[data[i].next].freq". how does it maps in memory?

Comment: Yes, it inserts a new element to a sorted list. `data[data[i].next].freq` is the value(freq) of next element. Assume the list is {(1,1),(2,2),(3,4),(4,5),(3,3),(7,-1)} (As your former example), and i = 4. Then `data[i]` is (3,3) and `data[i].next` is 3. So `data[data[i].next].freq` equals to `data[3].freq` , which equals to 4.

Comment: Your code is absoutely correct but there will be one problem at last. IT WILL NOT GIVE THE OUTPUT AS I want.Eg. suppose if i take the input array{1 2 3 4}. your algo maintanis the index correctly, but what i want is it should add the elements in  increasing order (without doing sorting). suppose we add first two indexes elements of array, wich are "1" and "2" and i got "3" and i pass this freq in your function insert(struct node *data, int new_freq, int data_size).It then manages the index, Until here everything is fine.

Comment: But now on the second execution of data[data_size].freq=data[f].freq+data[s].freq;(where f is reading at odd index and and s at even); this will add at position {0,1},{2,3},{4,5} but what i want is that it should add the freq such that at second execution it should have "data[data_size].freq + data[s].freq, This data[data_size]freq i must get by return of  your insertfunction and then again i should use it in data[data_size].freq=data[f].freq+data[s].freq; and then again i call insert function all elements are added(But the first addition is always done at 0 and 1 index). Any idea to do that?

Comment: for more information you can see the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378703/huffman-implementation-without-sorting/21378746?noredirect=1#21378746